# Rotating an image around another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, trigonometry

I am currently developing a game for iphone in which there is a spinning asteroid(which is circular) and an object spinning around the circumference of that asteroid. I have made calculations for the object to spin around the circumference of the asteroid using x = center.x + radius*cosf(degrees in radians) and y = center.y + radius*sinf(degrees in radians.) The only question I have is this: How much should I change the value of 'degrees' per frame in the object spinning around the circle to keep the image rotating so it appears to be moving around the circle but without rotating too much and how do I calculate something like that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide how many revolutions per minute you want then replace "degrees in radians" from your example with "revolutions/minute * minutes * 2pi". You can replace "minutes" with any time measurement.

Comment: 60 seconds. :-) Or any time period you want, really. If you want a revolution to take 20 seconds, you could replace "degrees in radians" with "0.05 * seconds * 2pi" where "seconds" is the number of seconds elapsed since the animation started.